# Garmin Edge 1030 and Di2 Connection

Tags: garmin, shimano-di2

I just got a Garmin Edge 1030, and have newer Ultegra Di2 with the buttons on the hoods. I was excited to see that the Garmin can connect to Di2. When I look for it in the sensors, it is not coming up. Do I need to add an ANT+ transmitter to my current Di2 setup? I am not sure, or is that something that should already be installed and the problem is else where?

Comment: You'll need the Di2 transmitter installed and most certainly an update for the Di2 firmware as well.

Comment: You need this transmitter: EW-WU111 Di2 ANT+ but you must have either the BT-DN110 or the BM-DN100 battery in the system.

Comment: Is the transmitter typically an add on, and not something that comes standard? I have a Trek Emonda SL7. There is not much detail on the Di2 https://www.trekbikes.com/us/en_US/bikes/road-bikes/performance-road/%C3%A9monda/%C3%A9monda-sl/%C3%A9monda-sl-7-disc/p/22110/

Comment: Unless stated otherwise in the specifications of said bike, the transmitter is typically an add-on. If it is installed on your bike it should show up under 'sensors' as 'DI2' on your head-unit if Di2 isn't in sleep mode, meaning a button has been touched recently. Note: If you buy a transmitter you'll also need a short length of e-tube wire.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install a D-Fly unit. Probably this one:  EW-WU111
Being able to use the Garmin in rain and cold weather with gloves is brilliant.
However check if you have the right components: these batteries are ok: BT-DN110 / BM-DN100